# Torrent Protocol find peer

Tags: bittorrent, peer, torrent

I am studying bit torrent protocol. I have confusion regarding torrent protocol. Suppose I have a router with static IP and two clients are connected to that router that are C1 and C2. One of that client say C1 is acting as a seed. Now how will the client downloading the file will know that C1 is seeding taking consideration the fact the only thing know to the outer-network is static IP of the router.
Is there is any way through which torrent can identify the client C1 ??? Please explain that.

Answer (score 1):

a) they can find each other via [local service discovery](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/729a8e91522fa53acc371365e9c29e910ed2a1e9/src/lsd.cpp#L60-L84), it's widely deployed but [currently lacking a specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_1000.html)

b) they can talk to each other through their respective public socket addresses as discovered through other peer discovery mechanisms if the router supports [hairpin NAT routing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6047391/1362755)

---

**Update**: Now there's [a spec for LSD](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0014.html).

Comment: Thanks, Since I am newbee to all this. Can you please explain how this local service directory works.

Comment: Are you asking me to reverse-engineer code for you?